# Font-awesome in `<fieldset>` with bootstrap 4 forms

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

For single-input forms in bootstrap 4, a nice way to place font-awesome icons is the `input-group-addon` class:

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
    </span>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email address">
</div>
```

which renders like this:

[image]

However, for multipart forms, it seems like bootstrap 4 is implicitly advising the use of the `<fieldset>` tag, but the natural extension of this idiom doesn't work:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
        </span>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email address">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

and it renders with the icon on top:

[image]

Is there a way to get the icon to set to the left of the field without writing custom css?

Comment: It's because you're wrapping the `input-group-addon` and `form-control` within the `<fieldset>` which is set as the parent `form-group`. Create an extra `<div>` or `<p>` around the `input-group-addon` and the `form-control` and give that the class of `form-group`

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your `form-group` class to `input-group`:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <fieldset class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
        </span>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email address">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you're wrapping the `input-group-addon` and `form-control` within the `<fieldset>` which is set as the parent `form-group`.

Create an extra `<div>` or `<p>` around the `input-group-addon` and the `form-control` and give that the class of `form-group` instead.

Like so:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                </span>
            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Email address">
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I *think* that you can also get rid of the `span` around the font-awesome icon, too. You can put that `input-group-addon` class as part of the `<i>` tag. Can't remember without trying it out myself. Don't hold me to it, but try and see.

Like this:

```
<i class="fa fa-envelope input-group-addon"></i>
```

Comment: Hmm, did't work for me. I'm using the following versions of bootstrap and font-awesome:   `<link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-y3tfxAZXuh4HwSYylfB+J125MxIs6mR5FOHamPBG064zB+AFeWH94NdvaCBm8qnd"
          crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet"
          href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.1/css/font-awesome.min.css"
          integrity="sha384-hQpvDQiCJaD2H465dQfA717v7lu5qHWtDbWNPvaTJ0ID5xnPUlVXnKzq7b8YUkbN"
          crossorigin="anonymous">`

Comment: I've not used Bootstrap 4 yet, to be honest. Don't know if there's any major changes or bugs (seeing as its in alpha release at the minute). Next step for me, would be to check against latest stable release of Bootstrap (3.2.something I think) and see if you're getting the same problem. Sorry couldn't be more help.